# LetsEncrypt expiration certificate date issue

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, auto-renewing

I am using Let’s encrypt on my production server to handle SSL certificate. 
My website certificate will expire next week so I regenerated it using the `letsencrypt-auto renew` command (I didn’t set cron task yet)

The last log I get is `2016-08-20 17:12:20,305:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:no renewal failures` which mean certificate has been successfully regenerated

But when I go back to my website and check the certificate properties it still says that it will expire next week.

So:

- Does Let’s Encrypt wait the last day of certificate to update its new expiration in browser ?
- Did my new certificate is not working properly which explain browser still give me next week as expiration ?

Can someone help me to clarify the way certificates expiration date works ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Let's Encrypt community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/info-expiration-certificate-date/19194/3), I have been able to figured out what was wrong: I just needed to reload my Nginx server and it updated the expiration time for certificate !

Comment: Had the same issue. Thanks for answering your own question for others like me!

Answer (score 0):

I'll just follow up here with a bit more information, for those who are looking at this question for answers.

If you have the renew running in crontab, and you have this issue, you can specify command option: `--post-hook 'some command'`.  And that `'some command'` should be the shell command necessary to reload your web server.

Comment: Now if I could just figure out why I'm still getting emails from LetsEncrypt saying my cert is expiring... (it's not).

Answer (score 0):

Though coming late, might be useful to someone.
Even after restarting apache I still had the issue. A full machine reboot solved it for me. This will be useful only if you have full control of the server machine though.